# date_create_from_format equivalent for PHP 5.2 (or lower)

Tags: php, date

I'm working with PHP 5.3 on my local machine and needed to parse a UK date format (dd/mm/yyyy).  I found that `strtotime` didn't work with that date format, so I used `date_create_from_format` instead - which works great.

Now, my problem is that my staging server is running PHP 5.2, and `date_create_from_format` doesn't work on that version. (It's a shared server, and wouldn't have a clue how to upgrade it to PHP 5.3)

So is there a similar function to `date_create_from_format` that I can use? Bespoke or PHP native?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `strptime` is not available to you, then here is a different idea. It is similar to Col. Shrapnel's approach but instead uses `sscanf` to parse the date-part values into variables and uses those to construct a new `DateTime` object.

```
list($day, $month, $year) = sscanf('12/04/2010', '%02d/%02d/%04d');
$datetime = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");
echo $datetime->format('r');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`strptime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) which is available in PHP 5.1 and above.

Comment: Thanks Dav. Yes, I'm on Windows for local dev (using XAMPP, PHP 5.3), but staging and live servers are LAMP, so this would work as a fall-back.

Answer (score 2):

include this code:

```
function DEFINE_date_create_from_format()
{

  function date_create_from_format( $dformat, $dvalue )
  {

    $schedule = $dvalue;
    $schedule_format = str_replace(array('Y','m','d', 'H', 'i','a'),array('%Y','%m','%d', '%I', '%M', '%p' ) ,$dformat);
    // %Y, %m and %d correspond to date()'s Y m and d.
    // %I corresponds to H, %M to i and %p to a
    $ugly = strptime($schedule, $schedule_format);
    $ymd = sprintf(
        // This is a format string that takes six total decimal
        // arguments, then left-pads them with zeros to either
        // 4 or 2 characters, as needed
        '%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d',
        $ugly['tm_year'] + 1900,  // This will be "111", so we need to add 1900.
        $ugly['tm_mon'] + 1,      // This will be the month minus one, so we add one.
        $ugly['tm_mday'], 
        $ugly['tm_hour'], 
        $ugly['tm_min'], 
        $ugly['tm_sec']
    );
    $new_schedule = new DateTime($ymd);

   return $new_schedule;

  }
}

if( !function_exists("date_create_from_format") )
  DEFINE_date_create_from_format();
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately I wasn't able to put it into work with format 'Y-m-d H:i:s' even after I added mapping from 's' to '%S'...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse only one particular format, it's elementary string operation.

```
list($d,$m,$y)=explode("/",$datestr);
```

Comment: this only gives him three strings, not the parsed date

Comment: @stereofrog uh oh what a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

use format DD-MM-YY and timestamp, I think it will be easier for you

```
$date="31-11-2015";
$timestamp=strtotime($date);
$dateConvert=date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
echo $dateConvert;
```

I've used it