# php date reformat

Tags: php, datetime

I need a function that takes any date/time and re formats it to a different format.

e.g.

`$date = "31/12/2010 15:00:00"` => has a format of `d/m/Y H:i:s`
so if i need a different format like

`$returning_format = "m/d/Y H:i:s"` => for America date/time

`$newdate = transoform_date($current_format,$returning_format,$date);`
the above line should return `12/31/2010 15:00:00`

NOTE: I don't need it for this format only coz i can explode it and re-arrange it, so it can accept any format and return the desired format date.

Comment: Userful links for the @Mchl Answer "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621433/date-create-from-format-equivalent-for-php-5-2-or-lower"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PHP 5.3+

`$newdate = DateTime::createFromFormat($current_format,$date)->format($returning_fomrat);`

Comment: Most shared hosting companies allow you to use php 5.2.6 therefore is practically as good as leaving it as it is or better than as it will throw php errors

Comment: You can only foorce them to adpot 5.3 by putting pressure on them ;) Luckily 5.2.16 is the last release in 5.2

Comment: I am working for a company if i forced them for each clients I would waste a hell of alot of my time befriending the hosting company for a datetime lol not practical (yet) but +1 for exact function as described on the answer

Comment: This is kinda useful :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621433/date-create-from-format-equivalent-for-php-5-2-or-lower

Answer (score 2):

strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

```
function transform_date($return_format, $date)
{
    return date($return_format, strtotime($date));
}
```

Comment: How does it know difference between `5-1-11` and `1-5-11`?

Comment: thats wat was putting me off aswell :)

Comment: strtotime on php.net tells us: Valid formats are explained in http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: Don't get me wrong, strtotime is great as long as you feed it correct formats. The question was however about parsing ANY format, as long as the format specification is given.

Comment: oki , let's say you pass that time and it doesn't work as expected , you'd use @Mchi example you'd have to know the current date format , do you know it or not ? if not then the best option would be to use this .

Comment: `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.`

Comment: btw i do know what the current format is and the format i want it to be :)