# Explode date/time string into assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have a string returning from a DB option, that allows the user to set her/his date format:

```
F j, Y
```

which would (for today) then return the following value in my `get_date()` function:

```
string 'September 24, 2012' (length=18)
```

Now I need an associative array that splits that string:

```
array( 
    'day'   => 24,
    'month' => 'September',
    'year'  => 2012
)
```

As don't know how the user sets her/his date, I have the problem that I can't simply say `F = month, j = day, Y = year`. Everything that the [php `date()` function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) allows, is allowed in the system.

> **Question:** How can I "match" those? Is there some native function that I've overseen, that tells me if something is a month/day/year/hour/...?

**Edit:** The max. PHP version I can use is PHP 5.2.1

Comment: Why aren't you storing the timestamp in the db?

Comment: Store a plain `DATETIME`, then format it at retrieval time, but don't save it in custom format - how about making a date-based query?

Comment: I'd say you've overseen to quickly scan the list of functions inside the date extension. Didn't you? Also storing that way in the database is doing the work on the wrong end. Or is this wordpress and you can't change that?

Comment: @hakra What should I say: It's like wordpress does it by default.

Comment: You should really ask the hoster to upgrade their PHP version if possible imho. 5.2.1 was released 08 Feb 2007. That's more than 5 years ago. [And isn't supported anymore](http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-16-1).

Comment: @PeeHaa As I said: It's wordpress. And as all system come with standard requirements, the min. version for WP is PHP 5.2.1. I'm writing open source plugins and such and therefore it should work for all users, not just on my server.

Comment: Minimum version or maximum version? Where in you question / tags do you mention wordpress? Do I need a pair of glasses?? (might just be the case) :P

Answer (score 4):

If you have PHP 5.3 or later, use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($inputFormat, $gotDate);

$result = array(
    'day' => (int)$date->format('j'),
    'month' => $date->format('F'),
    'year' => (int)$date->format('Y')
);
```

Comment: +1, but my failure to not state this (updated question). The **max. PHP version** that I can use **is PHP 5.2.1** - hence my answer with `date_parse()`. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: The problem left is that I still don't know if I should map `j` to `day`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you shouldn't store that string in the database in the first place, but use the timestamp.

If you do that you could use something like:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($theTimestamp);
$date = array(
    'day' => $dateTime->format('j'),
    'month' => $dateTime->format('F'),
    'year' => $dateTime->format('y'),
);
```

If you want to be flexible as to what you want in the array you could create a function like:

```
function buildDateArray($theTimestamp, $elements) {
    $dateTime = new DateTime($theTimestamp);
    $date = array();
    foreach($elements as $key => $format) {
        $date[$key] = $dateTime->format($format);
    }
}

$theArray = buildDateArray($theTimestamp, array(
    'day' => 'j',
    'month' => 'F',
    'year' => 'y',
));
```

*Note: the `DateTime` is available as of 5.2.0*

Comment: My problem with this is, that I still don't know if `j` belongs to `day`, `F` to `month`, etc.

Comment: As I wrote in the question: I got a user setting. That can be `F j, Y` as well as `m/d/Y`. So I'd need to know if there's a possibility to map those, so I don't have to force the user to edit a template to add the `'day' => 'j'` array to map them.

Comment: In my second example (the function) you can easily map it.

Comment: Depending on the user setting? From the question: _"As don't know how the user sets her/his date, I have the problem that I can't simply say F = month, j = day, Y = year. Everything that the php date() function allows, is allowed in the system."_. So how would your function do that? It needs the user to define the mapping.

Comment: I misread that part. But can't you just insert the timestamp in the db as I stated in my answer? (Don't know WP luckily).

Answer (score 1):

As you've now wrote that you do not have PHP 5.3 at hand (really a pity), so you need to parse the string "by hand". Next to PCRE regular expressions, there is also `sscanf`. Example:

```
$date = 'September 24, 2012';
$result = sscanf($date, '%s %2d, %4d', $month, $day, $year);
$parsed = array(
    'day'   => $day,
    'month' => $month,
    'year'  => $year
);
var_dump($parsed);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  'day' =>
  int(24)
  'month' =>
  string(9) "September"
  'year' =>
  int(2012)
}
```

This will already parse the input date string according to your format. If you need this more flexible, the pattern needs to be built dynamically, as well as associating the values to the result array.

I've compiled another example that does this. It might be a little fragile (I've added some notes), however it does work. Naturally I would wrap this into a function an better deal with the error conditions but I've keep the code raw, so that it better shows how it works:

```
// input variables:
$date = 'September 24, 2012';
$format = 'F j, Y';

// define the formats:
$formats = array(
    'F' => array('%s',  'month'),  # A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March
    'j' => array('%2d', 'day'),    # Day of the month, 2 digits with or without leading zeros
    'Y' => array('%4d', 'year'),   # A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
    # NOTE: add more formats as you need them
);

// compile the pattern and order of values
$pattern = '';
$order = array();
for($l = strlen($format), $i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    $c = $format[$i];

    // handle escape sequences
    if ($c === '\\') {
        $i++;
        $pattern .= ($i < $l) ? $format[$i] : $c;
        continue;
    }

    // handle formats or if not a format string, take over literally
    if (isset($formats[$c])) {
        $pattern .= $formats[$c][0];
        $order[] = $formats[$c][1];
    } else {
        $pattern .= $c;
    }
}

// scan the string based on pattern
// NOTE: This does not do any error checking
$values = sscanf($date, $pattern);

// combine with their names
// NOTE: duplicate array keys are possible, this is risky,
//       write your own logic this is for demonstration
$result = array_combine($order, $values);

// NOTE: you can then even check by type (string/int) and convert
//       month or day names into integers

var_dump($result);
```

The result in this case then is:

```
array(3) {
  'month' =>
  string(9) "September"
  'day' =>
  int(24)
  'year' =>
  int(2012)
}
```

Take care of the notes. Before I wrote it, I've checked the user-notes in the PHP manual, but the functions offered there are only for parsing one specific pattern, whereas this variant should be extensible to a certain degree. If you only have that one format, you can naturally create the sscanf string non dynamically.

See also: [date_create_from_format equivalent for PHP 5.2 (or lower)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621433/date-create-from-format-equivalent-for-php-5-2-or-lower)

Also take care that as this is wordpress, the month names might be translated.

And I'm pretty sure you can get the date of a post also in timestamp format. For a plugin it might be less burdensome to just aquire that value based on the post ID instead of parsing some string.

And a final note: Only Wordpress has a minimum PHP version, it must not mean your plugin needs that exact minimum version, too. Especially in the case you outline, PHP 5.2 does not get any support any longer (it's dead), and you could do your plugins users the favor to tell them that they should update their PHP version.

It looks like that Wordpress still misses to give warnings about the PHP version, they stop with browsers and their own software somehow ;) There is no need to mimic that bad practice. Tell your users that they are in danger and scare the hell out of them (or do shiny popup-bubbles to get the message over in a less threatening way. Do your users a service with good intentions, then there is something to win for both sides, do some kind of graceful fallback to show your good attitude).

See also: [Is there a Wordpress version that is incompatible with PHP 5.3?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28603/is-there-a-wordpress-version-that-is-incompatible-with-php-5-3)

You find the current release cycle of PHP outlined on PHP.net: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/releaseprocess if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Already found the first part of the answer in the native php `DateTime` class: Just use [`date_parse( get_date() );`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php). *Available since PHP 5.2*

```
// @example
'year' => int 2012
'month' => int 9
'day' => int 24
'hour' => boolean false
'minute' => boolean false
'second' => boolean false
'fraction' => boolean false
'warning_count' => int 0
'warnings' => 
   array
   empty
'error_count' => int 0
'errors' => 
   array
   empty
'is_localtime' => boolean false
```

This answer still doesn't solve the problem, that I don't know how to map `j` to `day`, `F` to `month`, etc.

Comment: You could run into ambiguities, though. `d/m/Y` and `m/d/Y`, anyone?

Comment: @minitech I just tried the common english and central european strings and they work, but you're right: That wouldn't work, as it's not meant to exist :P

Comment: Anyway, you can't do this. `date_parse` just figures out the format by itself, and it's usually right, I think. But I can also write a shiv for `DateTime::createFromFormat` if you'd like :)

Comment: If I'd know what a "shiv" is, then maybe? Ok, just do it ;)