# How to convert (very) old dates in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date, php-5.2

I have to migrate an Access database to MySQL. I have two problems: first is year is specified with two digits; second is that this is a birthday database. For example I have strings like this:

```
"06/12/76 00:00:00"
"10/15/02 00:00:00"
```

Which year is refering last one (October 15th)? I'll assume that all dates which have a year value over 12 are refering to 19XX and the other (from 0 to 12) to this century: 20XX.

Once resolved this problem I need to format these dates. I've try this:

```
$bd = strtotime($birth);
if ($bd > time()) {
    $bd = strtotime("-100 years", $bd);
}
$birth = sua_date_unix2mysql($bd);
```

But the problem is `strtotime` only is able to manage dates after 1970. Any idea to resolve this problem?

**NOTE**: Datetime is not available (version 5.2)

Comment: Upgrade PHP otherwise, have fun solving this ;). Most date questions here are pretty crippled due to low quality questions and answers, so don't get disappointed fast when searching the site. It's rough for the keywords, but I'm pretty sure there are some gems that explain it very well how it works.

Comment: Use DateTime objects, or upgrade to a 64-bit version of PHP to handle a full date range that should satisfy the average cosmologist... DateTime is available as an extension, even in PHP 5.1.x, though I'd recommend upgrading your PHP to a supported version anyway

Comment: why cant you let MS Access return the dates in a format that is easier to migrate?

Comment: @Gordon Because the dates aren't stored as 'date', are simple strings :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just manipulate those dates as strings.

```
// "06/12/76 00:00:00"
list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $birth);
// $year is actually "76 00:00:00"...
$year = (int)$year;

$century = 2000;
if (($century + $year) > date('Y'))
    $century = 1900;
$year += $century;
$mysql = "$year-$month-$day"; // 19760612 will be recognized by MySQL
```

Comment: why not just format it correctly `"$year-$month-$day"`, or `"$year-$month-$day 00:00:00"`. it's more readable and exactly how mysql presents date/datetime fields

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is fitting, but you can do this with string manipulation pretty easily.

First parse the incomming string to the values. For parsing the string, you can make use of `sscanf`.

```
$date = '06/12/76 00:00:00';
$result = sscanf(
    $date, '%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d', 
    $month, $day, $year, $hour, $minute, $second
);
```

Then expand the year from two letters to four letters. That should be fairly easy, a simple `if`.

```
$year += $year < 36 ? 2000 : 1900
```

Then re-arrange the strings to the date-format you need for mysql. For concatenating the string you can make use of `sprintf`.

```
$iso = sprintf(
    '%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', 
    $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second
);
```

Comment: sorry, I had deleted my "this looks like c" comment right before your reply - since it was just noise.

Comment: Well sometimes comments are noise ;) Anyway thanks for the feedback, I improved the answer a little. Some related code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12663862/367456